# C - How many hours is in certain amount of days?

Tags: c, days

I am learning C and Im writing a simple program where you enter number of days, and it says how much hours are in that days. For example, you enter 2 days, and it says there are 48 hours. There is no error, but the end result is not good.
Here is my code and my result
Code:

```
int day, hour;
hour= 24 * day;

printf("Find out how many hours are in days.\n");
printf("Enter number of days. Days = ");
scanf("%d", &day);
printf("%d days has %d hours.\n", day, hour);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);`
```

Here is the result in the console.

```
Find out how many hours are in days.
Enter number of days. Days = 1
1 days has 677268864 hours.
```

Comment: Why the downvote? There is code here and actual and expected behaviour documented.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I didn't downvote, but some users on SO feel that questions that make one go "well duh!"  shouldn't be here.

Comment: But some languages do allow this and the question is well written.

Comment: @Bathsheba - (*shrug*) I suppose it's just the feeling that such questions must have a duplicate, and yet said duplicate always being so elusive, that make people resent the question. I usually lean towards Joel Spolsky's philosophy that any question has a place on SO, at least once. But at some point it really is pedagogically better to sent people off to finding the answer on their own. </ramble>

Comment: Question is well written and has a code sample with a (to the OP) non obvious bug. It clearly states the behavior and thus I upvote the question. It is also non trivial to fin a matching duplicate to 'you shall first read the value and then use it, not the other way round'

Comment: Just in case: https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#dates-and-time

Answer (score 2):

You need to evaluate `hour` once `day` is known. You can't schedule an evaluation like that in C, if you get my meaning. (You can, interestingly in C++, using actors.)

Currently you are reading an uninitialised variable. The behaviour on doing that is undefined.

Comment: Got my vote, since I now googled actor framework implementations and have some reading material.

Comment: Have a look at boost spirit and boost Phoenix!

Comment: Will do. And I hope your cat is well and accounted for with all the UB on SO these days!

Comment: They came back after someone wrote the expression c/c++

Answer (score 2):

```
int day, hour;
hour= 24 * day;
```

The above sets `hour` to be the **current** indeterminate value of `day` times 24. It doesn't mean that `hour` will update automatically every time `day` changes.

Move this assignment to after you got the value of `day` from the user.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you're doing:

```
int day, hour;
```

`day` and `hour` are both **uninitialized**.

```
hour= 24 * day;
```

Then you immediately calculate `hour`! But `day` doesn't have any meaningful value.

In fact...

```
scanf("%d", &day);
```

...you're filling `day` after the calculation.

---

Move the `scanf` before the calculation so that `day` will be initialized while performing the multiplication - your code will work properly then.

Answer (score 2):

why are you doing this:

```
hour= 24 * day;
```

before the user gives the input??

that is the reason, you are calculating the answer before the input using   not initialized variable (and holding some unpredictable garbage...)

it must be something like

```
int day = 0;
int hour = 0;

printf("Find out how many hours are in days.\n");
printf("Enter number of days. Days = ");
scanf("%d", &day);
hour= 24 * day;
printf("%d days has %d hours.\n", day, hour);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Did not know I am not supposed to do that before the user inputs. I just thought that it will define hours and will automaticly figure it out.

Comment: @brs Sounds like you're a C++ programmer in the making.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `day` has not been filled yet; it likely contains junk data. To fix this, move the `int hours = day * 24` after the `scanf("%d",&day);`, this way the variable `day` will actually have the value scanned in.